# syntax error with try loop

Tags: php, syntax, try-catch, syntax-error

I keep getting a syntax error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in contact_form.php on line 18
```

but I cannot seem to be able to find it, heres the code

```
<?php
require_once('classes/class.phpmailer.php');
include_once("classes/class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within         class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded
include_once("includes/contact_form_constants.php"); 
include('funcs.php');
$errors='';
if((isset($_FILES['file']))&&(($_FILES['file']['error']==2)||($_FILES['file']    ['error']==1))){
echo "The file you tried to upload is too large. Please try again with a smaller file     2";
header('Location: ../result.php?title=Form Submission&msg=3');
}else if(($_FILES['file']['name']!=='')&&($_FILES['file']['error']>2) &&($_FILES['file']    ['error']!==4)){
$msg = 'apperently there has been an error in the contact form from the     electropolishing contact form, should probably get on it<br/>';
$msg.= 'here is some information on the file that the user tried to upload<br />';
$msg.= 'the error that was give was code #'.$_FILES['file']['error'].'<br/>';
$msg.= 'You can find more information about on the codes <a href="http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php">here.</a><br/>';
$msg.= "<br/> sent on ".date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
$error_email = new PHPMailer(true); // the true param means it will throw     exceptions on errors, which we need to catch
$error_email->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
//this is line 18
try {
//end of line 18
    $error_email->SMTPDebug  = 1;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
    $error_email->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
    $error_email->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
```

I have tested this same code in my local enviroment without any problems but the host i'm using is running php 4.4.9, i don't know if that seems to be the issue

Comment: where is the end "}" of try block ?

Comment: update your PHP to verion 5.x and you should be fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> PHP 5 has an exception model similar to that of other programming languages.

([Source](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php))

PHP 4 does not support `try..catch`.